# "Lighthouse was unable to download a robots.txt file" despite the file being accessible

Tags: node.js, robots.txt, content-security-policy, next.js, lighthouse

I have a **NodeJS/NextJS** app running at http://www.schandillia.com. The project has a **robots.txt** file accessible at http://www.schandillia.com/robots.txt. As of now, the file is bare-bones for testing purposes:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

However, when I run a Lighthouse audit on my site, it throws a **Crawling and Indexing error** saying it couldn't download a *robots.txt* file. I repeat, the file is available at http://www.schandillia.com/robots.txt.

The project's codebase, should you need to take a look, is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost. The *robots.txt* file is located at `proost/web/static/` but accessible at root thanks to the following in my Nginx config:

```
# ... the rest of your configuration
  location = /robots.txt {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/robots.txt;
  }
```

The complete config file is available for review on github at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/.help_docs/configs/nginx.conf.

Please advice if there's something I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Your `robots.txt` is served fine, but Lighthouse can not fetch it properly because its audit can currently not work with the [`connect-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) directive of of your site’s Content Security Policy, due to a known limitation which <s>is being tracked as issue [#4386](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/4386)</s> was [fixed in Chrome 92](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/12423).

---

**Explanation:** Lighthouse attempts to fetch the `robots.txt` file by way of a script ran from the document served by the root of your site. Here is the code it uses to perform this request (found in [lighthouse-core](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/gather/gatherers/seo/robots-txt.js)):

```
const response = await fetch(new URL('/robots.txt', location.href).href);
```

If you try to run this code from your site, you will notice that a “Refused to connect” error is thrown:

[image: Screenshot of the “Refused to connect” error]

This error happens because the browser enforces the Content Security Policy restrictions from the headers served by your site (split on several lines for readability):

```
content-security-policy:
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com;
    img-src 'self' *.google-analytics.com;
    connect-src 'none';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com;
    font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com;
    object-src 'self';
    media-src 'self';
    frame-src 'self'
```

Notice the `connect-src 'none';` part. Per [the CSP spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#directive-connect-src), it means that no URL can be loaded using script interfaces from within the served document. In practice, any `fetch` is refused.

This header is explicitly sent by the server layer of your by Next.js application, because of the way you configured your [Content Security Policy middleware](https://github.com/helmetjs/csp) (from [commit a6aef0e](https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/commit/a6aef0ef4e23a7836ba57cd9d8198d31bc1de471#diff-5ea216fa13019bfada6d0326e01aa7bbR32)):

```js
import csp from 'helmet-csp';

server.use(csp({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    scriptSrc: ["'self'", '*.google-analytics.com'],
    imgSrc: ["'self'", '*.google-analytics.com'],
    connectSrc: ["'none'"],
    styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com'], // Remove unsafe-inline for better security
    fontSrc: ["'self'"],
    objectSrc: ["'self'"],
    mediaSrc: ["'self'"],
    frameSrc: ["'self'"]
  }
}));
```

---

**Solution/Workaround:** To solve the problem in the audit report, you can either:

- wait for (or submit) a fix in Lighthouse
- use the `connect-src 'self'` directive, which will have the side effect of allowing HTTP requests from the browser side of your Next.js app