# How can I solve "Lighthouse was unable to download a robots.txt file" if all code seems correct?

Tags: next.js, robots.txt, lighthouse

I'm making Next.JS app and using `next-sitemap` plugin for generating sitemap.xml and robots.txt files. All is fine, but sometimes Google Lighthouse give me an error (on screenshot):

[image: robots.txt Lighthouse error]

My robots.txt file is on https://webnos.online/robots.txt.

I've found this error and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441731/lighthouse-was-unable-to-download-a-robots-txt-file-despite-the-file-being-acc), but running `await fetch(new URL('/robots.txt', location.href).href)` in console returns correct result (on screenshot) unlike found solution:

[image: console result]

Other audit services didn't show me any errors with robots.txt file. How can I fix this error or could I ignore it?

Comment: I have faced this couple of times as well. But when trying second time, didnt get the error. Probaby some sporadic network error. try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469252/8803194), If you are facing the issue even on retries

Comment: @RGog I've tried adding `connect-src: 'self'`, but error still appears. May be in CSP policy I should to add more than one `connect-src` note?

Comment: I was getting this issue in Opera. Switching to Chrome and using Lighthouse made the issue disappear

Comment: In Chrome I have the same issue. But, when I switched my hosing service to Vercel problem was solved. P.S. before Vercel I used Netlify.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I moved to Vercel hosting the problem was solved. Before that I used Netlify.